# Spring Dynamic Constructor Value

Tags: java, spring

My English is not good. Please understand..

```
//This is my Spring-mvc-based Controller
@Controller

public class DownloadManageController {
    private DownloadManageService downService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPackService(DownloadManageService downService) {
        this.downService = downService;
    }
}

//This is my Spring-Bean which should have a dynamic value of contructor
Component

public class DownloadManageService {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DownloadManageService.class);
    private FileAccessObject downloadFileAccessObj = null;

    DownloadManageService(String downloadInfoFile) {
        this.downloadFileAccessObj = new FileAccessObjectImpl(
                "d:/dat/download/" + downloadInfoFile);
    }

}
```

When Service inject into controller... I'd like to make `downloadInfoFile` variable dynamic depends on a request parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you create a factory class into which you can pass the path you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If it was I,I would do it as follow:

```
public class DownloadManageService {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DownloadManageService.class);
    private FileAccessObject downloadFileAccessObj = null;

    public DownloadManageService() {
    }

    public void setDownloadFileAccessObj... 
}

public class DownloadManageController {
    private DownloadManageService downService;

    @Autowired
    public void setPackService(DownloadManageService downService) {
        this.downService = downService;
    }

    public void exec(){
        ...
        this.downService.setDownloadFileAccessObj(new FileAccessObjectImpl(...))
        ...
    }
}
```